# Can I change how certain expressions are displayed/printed upon evaluation?

Tags: output-formatting, output, printing

I'm writing some operations for Young tableaus and I would like the evaluation of an expression of type  `young[a_]` to be printed the same as `Grid[a]` .

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Format` is very useful for changing the display form of expressions in general:

```
Format[young[x___], StandardForm] := Grid[x]
```

After evaluating this, all subsequent outputs of the form `young[...]` (which are typically in StandardForm) will be printed with `Grid` applied to the arguments.